# LibGDX Game Works as Expected on Desktop, But Not on Android Device

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm running into a bit of a problem. I'm a bit new to libGDX and have little idea of whats wrong. 
Here I have a state that has three instances of a text button. It works fine on my desktop, but crashes on my phone. I'm not sure what the problem is, but when I comment out the code for two of the instances, it works on my phone.

```
public class MenuStateTest extends State {

Stage stage;
TextButton button, button2, button3;
TextButton.TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle;
BitmapFont font;
Skin skin;
TextureAtlas buttonAtlas, button2Atlas, button3Atlas;

public MenuStateTest(GameStateManager gsm) {
    super(gsm);
    stage = new Stage();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    font = new BitmapFont();
    skin = new Skin();

    buttonAtlas = new TextureAtlas("buttonTest.pack");
    skin.addRegions(buttonAtlas);
    textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
    textButtonStyle.font = font;
    textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("1BBlock");
    textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("T1BBlock");
    button = new TextButton("", textButtonStyle);
    stage.addActor(button);
    button.setPosition(20,200);

    button2Atlas = new TextureAtlas("button2Test.pack");
    skin.addRegions(button2Atlas);
    textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
    textButtonStyle.font = font;
    textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("2BBlock");
    textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("T2BBlock");
    button2 = new TextButton("", textButtonStyle);
    stage.addActor(button2);
    button2.setPosition(175,200);

    button3Atlas = new TextureAtlas("button3Test.pack");
    skin.addRegions(button3Atlas);
    textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
    textButtonStyle.font = font;
    textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("3BBlock");
    textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("T3BBlock");
    button3 = new TextButton("", textButtonStyle);
    stage.addActor(button3);
    button3.setPosition(330,200);
}

@Override
protected void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    stage.draw();
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

EDIT: Here's what I was able to get from the logcat

```
03-23 11:44:54.510 25775-25799/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 2379
                                               Process: com.mygame.game.android, PID: 25775
                                               Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.blazze11.euphoria.dark, iconPack:system, fontPkg:system, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.blazze11.euphoria.dark, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:system}
                                               com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading file: button2Test.pack (Internal)
                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:77)
                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas$TextureAtlasData.<init>(TextureAtlas.java:103)
                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas.<init>(TextureAtlas.java:231)
                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas.<init>(TextureAtlas.java:226)
                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas.<init>(TextureAtlas.java:216)
                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas.<init>(TextureAtlas.java:211)
                                                   at com.mygame.game.States.MenuStateTest.<init>(MenuStateTest.java:41)
                                                   at com.mygame.game.MyGame.create(MyGame.java:29)
                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:243)
                                                   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1519)
                                                   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
                                                Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: button2Test.pack
                                                   at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
                                                   at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:331)
                                                   at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:305)
                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:75)
                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas$TextureAtlasData.<init>(TextureAtlas.java:103) 
                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas.<init>(TextureAtlas.java:231) 
                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas.<init>(TextureAtlas.java:226) 
                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas.<init>(TextureAtlas.java:216) 
                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas.<init>(TextureAtlas.java:211) 
                                                   at com.mygame.game.States.MenuStateTest.<init>(MenuStateTest.java:41) 
                                                   at com.mygame.game.MyGame.create(MyGame.java:29) 
                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:243) 
                                                   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1519) 
                                                   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

Comment: Please provide a stacktrace of the error

Comment: When I surround the last two button instances with a try and catch block, the code runs on my phone. But only the first button is rendered to the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it runs on desktop and doesn't run on Android, there are two possibilities that I can think of:

1. Check the path of the folder that contains the `button2Test.pack`
   file. Android paths are relative to the assets folder while the
   desktop uses a path relative to the root folder.
2. Check the case of name of the file `button2Test.pack` for example
   whether it should be `Button2Test.pack`, `button2test.PACK` or
   similar comobinations. Because Windows accepts any case files but
   Android doesn't.

Comment: Sure, is the file name. Must check on the file sistem for the right name.